# Previously visited pages are continually added to the background

Tags: jquery-mobile

As I click through my JQM site the page i visit is fine and I click through to the next and that is fine but displayed underneath is the previous page, and not only, as I keep visiting pages the previous pages keep getting added to this second, 'background' layer. (at the bottom, even twice if i visit the page twice!)

Why is this occuring? What settings have I not set properly? Is it related to cache or pageremove?

Notes

It is version 1.4 (latest stable JQM)

All new pages are accessed via SUBMIT (ie from a form) not links

All pages except the index are dynamic php pages

If you feel any particluar part of the code that is being used now is relevant, let me know, but i doubt it is.

Answer (score 0):

Jquery Mobile removes pages as it keeps updating the DOM, except in two cases.

1 All pages that are referenced directly, eg the index/arrival page (ist page loaded), are NOT removed (the doctype and head are kept you see).

2 All pages that are loaded via AJAX are removed, except FORMS.

So a site that navigates via forms will not have the pages removed.

So pages that are forms should be removed by inserting a new page. In effect reloading the jquery mobile. So doctype, head etc need to be included, as if each page is a landing page.

How to make a form create a new page?

use

```
data-ajax="false"
```

in the form properties.

Downside:
Now you are basically leaving the jqm structure you will not be able to use the nice loading page spinning wheel...

Added advantage
This does mean that external js files are reloaded directly too

If there is a solution which also allows the site to 'stay inside' JQM please post and I will accept it as the answer.

Answer (score -1):

try setup your jquery mobile using this setting

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function() {
    $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
    $.mobile.linkBindingEnabled = false;
    $.mobile.hashListeningEnabled = false;
    $.mobile.pushStateEnabled = false;
    // Remove page from DOM when it's being replaced
    $('div[data-role="page"]').live('pagehide', function(event, ui) {
        $(event.currentTarget).remove();
    });
});
```

check my sample code here: https://github.com/datomnurdin/service-finder-mobile

Comment: Thanks, not sure why you got the -1 exactly though

Comment: I answered too, I think someone didn-t like your .bind, is .on preferred now?

Comment: I'm using it without any problem. You can check my sample code here.
https://github.com/datomnurdin/service-finder-mobile

Comment: Thanks Dato, this evening I-ll run your code and see!! Thanks!

Comment: why do you recommend the linkBinding and the hashListening are disabled? I-m reading the docs but don't get the connection, sorry. Maybe a little explanation is req, thanks